# python multiprocessing: processes don't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to assign my computing jobs to more than one cpu, so I choose multiprocessing. However, the result is not what I want.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process

def func(begin,end):
    print('*'*5)
    print('begin=%d' %(begin))
    for i in range(begin,end):
        for j in range(10):
            myarray[i][j]=1

myarray=np.zeros((12,10))
print(myarray)
for i in range(4):
    begin=i*3
    end=(i+1)*3
    p=Process(target=func,args=(begin,end,))
    p.start()

print('*'*5)
print(myarray)
```

I think that myarray should be all ones. But it doesn't change at all. Why? The func function does not change elements of myarray? 
I tried the example from this link[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def f(name):
    print('hello',name)

p=Process(target=f,args=('bob',))
p.start()
```

It shows nothing on the screen. Why?
How should I finish my computation with python? Can anyone give a way of fully take advantage of multi-cpus?

Comment: Second snippet prints: `('hello', 'bob')`

Comment: @alfasin Seems to me it should. But I test that code using python 3.4.3 on win7 and corresponding code(the print function to statement) with python 2.6.6 on centos6.5 in virtual box. Neither show anything.

Comment: it works for me with python3.4 on Mac.

Comment: @alfasin Sorry. The second didn't work on win7 with python3.4.3. This is the platform I use to test simple programs. But it is okay with centos with python 2.6.6. I've checked that again. Although I cann't figure out why, it is the situation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems there:

1. When you print your array at the end, how do you know your processes have already finished? You need to invoke [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) on each process to ensure they have finished.
2. Each process has a copy of "myarray". If you want to communicate several processes you need to either use a `Queue` or a `Pipe`. Check [the documentation that talks about exchanging data between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Here is a working example using as base the one you posted (it is not intended to be fast, just to show how the communication is done):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support, Queue

def func(my_id, q, begin, end):
    global myarray
    print('Process %d has range: %d - %d' % (my_id, begin, end))
    for i in range(begin,end):
        q.put((i, i * 2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()

    q = Queue()
    processes = []
    myarray=[0] * 12
    print("At the beginning the array is ", myarray)

    for i in range(4):
        begin = i*3
        end = (i+1)*3
        p = Process(target=func, args=(i, q, begin, end))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    while not q.empty():
        (index, value) = q.get()
        myarray[index] = value

    print("At the end the array is ", myarray)
```

Try to change the line `p.join()` by `pass` to see what happens :)

Comment: Yes, join is a must. If I replace the p.join() with pass, some values are changed while others are not.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `print(myarray)` statement execute before the process end. You should wait for the process end and then execute this statement. Please note the `thread.join()` statement at the following.

```
import numpy as np
import threading

lock = threading.RLock()
thread_list = []
def func(begin,end):
    print('*'*5)
    print('begin=%d' %(begin))
    for i in range(begin,end):
        for j in range(10):
            with lock:
                myarray[i][j]=1

myarray=np.zeros((12,10))
print(myarray)
for i in range(4):
    begin=i*3
    end=(i+1)*3
    p=threading.Thread(target=func,args=(begin,end,))
    p.start()
    thread_list.append(p)

print('*'*5)
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
print(myarray)
```